# Does Visual Studio have "advanced save options"

Tags: newline, byte-order-mark, linefeed

Does Visual Studio have options such as:

- save as advanced opiton CRLF to LF
- save without BOM
- etc?

Comment: It could, but I'm guessing you meant to ask: Can Visual Studio do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Advanced Save Options Dialog Box

Use this dialog box to select a language encoding scheme and to specify the characters to be inserted at the end of each line. **To access this dialog box, open a code file for editing in Visual Studio 2010 and then click Advanced Save Options on the File menu**.

### Encoding

Use this list box to apply a new language encoding scheme to the target file.

### Line Endings

To ensure that the target file runs on a specific operating system, select whether a carriage return (for Macintosh systems), a line feed (for Unix systems), or both characters (for Windows systems) marks the end of each line.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66d2abf2(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thank you for quick response. about Visutal Studio Code  have  same function?

Comment: @jwpfox Are you sure you're not confusing Visual Studio and the open source text editor Visual Studio Code? The two products have completely different user interfaces and feature sets.